# How can I get text selected when category clicked on combobox ? (Vue.JS 2)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-resource

I have a vue component like this :

```
<script>
    export default{
        template: '\
            <select class="form-control" v-model="selected" v-on:change="search">\
                <option v-for="option in options" v-bind:value="option.id" v-bind:disabled="option.disabled">{{ option.name }}</option>\
            </select>',
        mounted() {
            this.fetchList();
        },
        data() {
            return {
                selected: '',
                options: [{id: '', name: window.trans.category.select}]
            };
        },
        methods: {
            search(e){
                window.location = window.BaseUrl + '/search?q=&cat=' + e.target.value;
            },
            fetchList: function() {
                this.$http.post(window.BaseUrl+'/category/list?parent_id=all').then(function (response) {
                    response.data.forEach(function(item){
                        this.options.push({id:item.id, name:item.name})
                    }, this);
                });
            },
        }
    };
</script>
```

When category clicked, I want get text of the category

On my code above, I use this : `e.target.value` to get id selected and it works

But, how can I get text selected when category clicked?

I try this : `e.target.text`, but id does not work

Is there anyone who can help me?

Comment: Isn't that in variable: `selected `, which you are using in `v-model`?

Comment: @Saurabh, I want to take the text. No value. If I  `console.log(this.selected)`, the result is value

Comment: Try using ` v-bind:value="option.name" ` instead, let me know.

Comment: @Saurabh, It works. But, whether there is no other way to get the text. Because I also need `v-bind:value="option.id"` to display the data

Answer (score 0):

Given you want both `id` and `name`, you can try this:

```
    template: '\
        <select class="form-control" v-on:change="search">\
            <option v-for="option in options" v-bind:value="option.id"  @click="selected=option.name" v-bind:disabled="option.disabled">{{ option.name }}</option>\
        </select>',
    mounted() {
        this.fetchList();
    },
```

Comment: How can I take it? I try `console.log(this.selected)`, the result is value id. No text

Comment: Seems it does not work. Because it call run `v-on:change="search"` first before call `@click`

Comment: Do you get some error, There are some corrections suggested [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42991343/how-can-i-add-selected-when-category-clicked-on-combobox-vue-js-2) as well.

Comment: I have a solution that is more brilliant, which is using jquery. Look at this : `$(".form-control option:selected").text()`